# jQuery "not readonly" selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm looking for something along the lines of...

```
$(':input:not(readonly)') // all inputs which are not readonly
```

but struggling to find the syntax.

Any pointers? thanks

Answer (score 152, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(":input:not([readonly])")
```

Answer (score 39):

```
$('input:not([readonly])')
```

would cover readonly, readonly="true" and readonly="readonly"

Answer (score 4):

I recently did something similar like this:

```
$('#element').find(':input').not(':input[readonly]');
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are looking for something like the following:

```
$('input:not([readonly="readonly"])')
```

Have a look at jQuery's various [attribute-selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add another answer that works for me, using context https://api.jquery.com/context/

```
$(this).context.readOnly == false / true
```