# jQuery set then read readonly attr on textbox

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-selectors

```
​<input id="test" type="text" value="text" />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

alert(​$(':input:not([readonly])').length);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ // 1

$('#test').attr('readonly', 'readonly');

alert($(':input:not([readonly])').length); // 1

$('#test').removeAttr('readonly');​​​​​​​​​​

alert($(':input:not([readonly])').length); // 1
```

Further to [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708764/jquery-not-readonly-selector), I can't get the solution to work because it seems jQuery doesn't set the readonly attribute correctly (or at least consistently).

Note I get the same results with `$('#test').attr('readonly', true);`

I'm using Chrome, and the readonly attribute renders as `readonly=""`. There is another post on here which suggests FireFox does the same.

I'm not much bothered about this in as much as it still stops the text box from being editable, but I can't then find a way to detect the readonly attribute.

I normally love jQuery but this is all a bit WTF.

Any ideas?

Comment: The reason you're seeing this behavior because the `[readonly]` selector just checks for the *presence* of the attribute, and `true` or `false`, it is present.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally wouldn't use removeAttr()...I'd just set it to false with attr().

You could then just query the property normally:

```
if ($("#X").attr("readonly"))
{
    execute code
}
```

Also, you can keep using removeAttr(), and then just use the length as a way to detect the property:

```
if (!$("#X").attr("readonly").length)
{
    execute code
}
```

If you're worried about the selector, you should do the selector syntax as `:not([readonly='readonly'])` **edit:** I see that was already in the answer you cited.

Comment: well ok, but it's the add attribute that is really causing the problem.

Comment: I'd just do the adding the same way: $("#X").attr("readonly",true);

Comment: also in this case, go by behavior, not by browser debuggers...sometimes they don't always track property changes like this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think even though you manage to disable the input pro-grammatically using Javascript, smart user will be able to change it if their disable the browser JavaScript. So to be safe it is best to reload the value in your server side.