# how to check whether a text field is readonly or not

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery “not readonly” selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708764/jquery-not-readonly-selector)

I have some text fields in a form. In this some text fields are editable and some are 'readonly'. so now I want to set values to the editable text fields only and must ignore the readonly text fields.
Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please find question before posting. There are lots of questions maybe asked before !!

Answer (score 5):

```
if ($('#foo').attr("readonly") == true){ }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($("#X").attr("readonly"))
{
    execute code
}
```

try this one...